# c# what does Sender represents in specific event

Tags: c#

I'm using DataRow changed/deleted/New events :

```
public IList<DataTable> _Tables { get; set; }
```

im listening to the events :

```
public void Listen()
{
    if (Manager != null)
    {
        foreach (var _table in this._Tables)
        {
            _table.RowChanged += _table_RowChanged;
            _table.RowDeleting += _table_RowDeleting;
            _table.TableNewRow += _table_TableNewRow;
        }
    }
}
```

in this events

```
    private void _table_TableNewRow(object sender, DataTableNewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        Manager.PerformAction(this, new DBchangedArgs
        { DBname = this.DBName, RowChanged = e.Row , rowAction = Enums.RowAction.Add });
    }
```

what does sender represents ?
is the object which contains the event or the object which has the rows (Table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `DataTable` instance from which the event was fired. See the DataTable source code [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/DataTable.cs#L3351-L3354).